# Why can I not add a check constraint that makes the user enter an email ending in a specific address

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Implementing: An employee email address should use the company domain. That is, the
email address should end with 'abcco.com'.

```
alter table employee
add constraint emp_email_check check (co_email in ('%abcco.com'));
```

but I get this error

```
ORA-02293: cannot validate (ITAM.EMP_EMAIL_CHECK) - check constraint violated
02293. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"
*Cause:    an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
           populated table that had nocomplying values.
*Action:   Obvious
```

Comment: LOL typical Oracle: _"Action: Obvious"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN()` predicate tests for exact string matches only. It does not support wildcards.

You should use

```
check (co_email like '%abcco.com')
```

Or alternatively:

```
check (left(co_email, 9) = 'abcco.com')
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first one and it worked. I can't believe it was that simple error lol

Comment: It was "obvious!" :-)

Comment: haha yea that made me feel really stupid

Comment: Oh don't say that! I'm trying to make fun of Oracle's unhelpful error message, not you! My philosophy is that error messages should tell you what happened and also tell you what you need to do to fix it. The Oracle error fails to do that. It's not your fault.

Comment: haha no I am not saying you made me feel stupid, it is oracle who made me feel stupid when it said "Obvious"